# WPF filtering ListView removes Selected Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am struggling with filtering of listView. I tried 2 methods to filter without selected items removed. 
My issue: whenever an selected item disappers because of the filter, it is no longer selected when it comes back. 
My methods:

Self written code:

```
            try
        {

            string s = isci_tb.Text;
            if (isci_tb.Text == "")
            {
                osebe_listView.Items.Clear();
                foreach (Oseba o in seznamOseb)
                {
                    osebe_listView.Items.Add(o);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                osebe_listView.Items.Clear();
                foreach (Oseba o in seznamOseb)
                {
                    if (contejns(o.ime, s) || contejns(o.priimek, s) || contejns(o.mobilnaSt.ToString(), s) || contejns(o.posta, s) || contejns(o.nazivPodjetja, s) || contejns(o.stacionarnaSt.ToString(), s) || contejns(o.naslov, s) || contejns(o.eMail, s))
                    {
                        osebe_listView.Items.Add(o);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
```

What this does is it searches all items and displayes only the one that matches with he filter, but this method removes items comepletly and re-adds them.
I tried to add a value for selected items, that saves onSelectionChanged and is used when the filter is changed, but it didn't work.

The second method was from [this tutorial.](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/) I was hoping it would work because it uses a Filter, but aparently, it has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `Visibility` of your ListViewItems depending on some property of `Oseba`. Then, instead of

```
osebe_listView.Items.Clear();
foreach (Oseba o in seznamOseb)
{
    if (someConditions)
    {
       osebe_listView.Items.Add(o);
    }
}
```

You could write something like this:

```
foreach (Oseba o in seznamOseb)
{
    if (someConditions) // when true, we want to hide the object
    {
       o.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

and in your .xaml file use a DataTemplate which sets the item's `Visibility` to `Collapsed` when `IsVisible` is set to false.

Another approach would be to store the `IsSelected`-state inside your object `Oseba`, so that when you remove and re-add the object to your listView, the selection state is persistent.

Comment: How could I set the o.isVisible property if there is none in Oseba? I think you want to set the not-equal-to-filter objects to visible=false, right? How could I do that? I'm trying it right now

Comment: I was under the assumption that you have control over the class `Oseba` and that you can define a property "IsVisible" on it.

Comment: Oseba is only a data class, which has properties, that are displayed in ListView

Comment: I added an IsSelected property to "Oseba", which is changed in the osebe_listView_SelectionChanged method. I used  var sel = e.AddedItems; var des = e.RemovedItems;   to alter the property. The problem now is, that it is set to false also when the item is removed due to filter. Any idea?

Comment: It's hard to tell, there could be quite a few places where things go wrong. I would suggest you edit your question and provide a more complete code sample, so that I and others can give better advice.